# Make screen reader read new page title in Angular app

Tags: html, angularjs, screen-readers

I have an angular app in which I am setting the titles of each page using the `$stateChangeSuccess` event handler. The titles are changing fine when I change the page.

Problem: From an accessibility standpoint, when a user changes the page in my app, the new title should be read out loud so he/she knows what page he is on. However, as this is a single page app, the title is not re-read by the screen reader.

I have read other questions on Stack Overflow regarding screen readers but they don't answer my question.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I read somewhere to use `aria-live="assertive"` so screen reader will be interrupted and forced to read I tried using the `aria-live="assertive"` attribute on the `<title>` tag. But screen reader is not reading the new title text when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `aria-label` directive, as seen [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility), and then modify the visibility of the element when it needs to appear.

Comment: Just to be clear I am talking about the `<title>` tag, not any <h> element that I am using as my title.